# Aptana flagging valid brackets as PHP syntax error

Tags: php, aptana

I'm new to Aptana, so don't quite have all of the behaviors sorted. I have PHP code that works, but Aptana is throwing syntax errors on both of the brackets:

```
public function addRecord($data)
{
    $request = [
        'action' => 'addrecord',
        'data' => json_encode($data)
    ];

    return $this->requestJson($request, 'POST');
}
```

What am I not seeing here?

Comment: This is a PHP 5.4 feature. Check in your Aptana preferences that your PHP interpreter supports 5.4.

Comment: Thank you very much. As I warned, I'm a n00b in Aptana; I don't see anything in preferences about versions for PHP.

Comment: It appears that Aptana does not support PHP 5.4 just yet. :-( https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4447

Comment: Then you can use `$request = array(...)` instead of `$request = [...]`

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Aptana does support PHP 5.4 now, whereas it didn't when the original post was made.

```
Project->Properties->PHP Development-> Select PHP 5.4.x
```

Comment: But, alas, there is another bug where the project always defaults back to 5.3 (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24633995) )