# aptana spurious syntax errors

Tags: syntax, aptana

what is beginning to drive me a bit crazy is that I googled "Aptana spurious syntax errors" ... and virtually nothing came up... I feel marooned.

I've tried refresh, opening and closing Aptana, even restarting my machine... nothing doing.  I've also tried to see if I can find a suitable "ignore this type of error" option in the configs...

The things that seem to be causing this are backticks ... even **in comments!** (but also in code)  and also square brackets ... which allow spaces around numbers... i.e. "[ 0 ]" causes a "syntax error", but it goes away if I change this to "[0]"... so yes, I found this question: [Aptana flagging valid brackets as PHP syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653125/aptana-flagging-valid-brackets-as-php-syntax-error)

Googling and searching "aptana backticks" or "aptana back ticks" comes up with nothing!  Using the Aptana help came up with nothing!  Anyone got any suggestions?

***later***

a strange explanation... which I leave for anyone who encounters the same problem.  Inadvertently I had left an isolated backtick in the middle of a php file... rather than flagging this, Aptana signalled syntax errors all over the place.

Comment: In what editor are you getting these errors? I tried `[ 0 ]` and backticks in the PHP Source Editor and in the HTML Editor inside of comments (`<!-- -->, /* */, and //`) with no complaints from Aptana...

Comment: @Sarah Thanks... Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.3.1.201212171919 - I started noticing these probs earlier today... so I presume that they weren't happending before

Comment: I am running 3.3.1.201212171919 as well...

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, and I am "solving" it by cutting the first block of code that shows errors to see if the errors go away. If they do, I paste the stuff back in--no errors :) Talk about silly..